# Issue with type conversion on .Visual Studio auto-generated controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Good afternoon, I'm working on a web application using **Visual Studio 2012** in version 11.0.6 and **MVC 4** project.

I created the data model within an **area** called *"backend"* and have **auto-generated controllers** such entities.

**Everything worked fine** high as that, today, to reopen the project to continue working and start the server that incorporates Visual Studio and launch the project, I found **75 errors**.

**All errors** correspond with the **auto-generated controllers**. It is these three, changing the entity to which they refer:

- Can not implicitly convert type 'SolMar.Areas.Backend.Models.Rol' in 'SolMar.Rol'
- The best overloaded method match 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(SolMar.Areas.Backend.Models.RoomType)' It has some invalid arguments
- Argument 1: You can not convert from 'SolMar.BoardType' a 'SolMar.Areas.Backend.Models.BoardType'

**I have not changed anything** about the project because currently **I was just changing the views** of the *backend*.

It is a **teaching project, to learn** how to properly use MVC and Visual Studio. I leave a link to download the project.

#### URL (23MB): https://mega.nz/#!X4JgRCQb!eIofWYE96s6a_T3mkKK-RqaINzPK9-sD5qToDFZW3P0

**Greetings, thank you**

Comment: Many people (including myself) will not download a project file from an untrusted random upload site and review it; unfortunately, it's more common than it should be to find more than just code in those downloads.

Comment: also, you should consider removing the 3 visual-studio tags from your code;  You mentioned the version that you are using (2012) but included two others, plus those tags specifically state that you should only use them when you have issues with the IDE itself, not issues with code you are writing using those IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have defined your models and database context twice in your solution. If you delete `Model1.edmx` in your solution then all controllers will point correctly to your Models and Context in Area/Backend and the project builds